# symfony5, I have an error 500 at my host when I put the application in prod and everything works fine when I put in dev

Tags: php, symfony5

Good evening ga, I have a problem that has persisted for some time that I can not debug, I had to develop a symfony 5.2 application, which works well locally on my machine in dev mode and which also works  at my host my only in dev mode, once I put it in prod mode at my host I have 500 errors that appear on certain route and also when I clean my cache and update, the page is  displays and once I refresh the error 500 comes back I have checked my logs no error message nothing to report, please I would like someone to help me as I am struggling with this problem  it's been a week already, thank you

Comment: Error 500 is a generic 'something wrong on the server` message. There **will** be a message in the server error log that tells you what went wrong.

Comment: Check that page: [Symfony Configuring Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments)